# Getting this issue in lambda console but locally its works No object dch for mime type multipart/mixed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, email-attachments, amazon-ses

I am creating an AWS Lambda function in java quarkus.

I am using java mail and Amazon SES for email.

I have all the required dependencies added and its running completely fine while testing locally through postman. I get all the attachments that is pdf file on email. But whenever I try to test in the AWS Lambda console I get this:

> no object dch for mime type multipart/mixed

I have tried adding the thread to load class and also:

```
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content- handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
```

but no luck as of now.  Any one knows some solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Java and Lambda but the error "no object dch for mime type multipart/mixed" occurs when the JavaMail library is not able to find the DataContentHandler for the specified MIME type. In this case, it's happening when running the code in the AWS Lambda console, but not when testing locally through Postman. This suggests that there may be an issue with the environment configuration in the AWS Lambda console.

One solution is to ensure that the necessary libraries are included in the deployment package of the AWS Lambda function. When testing locally, all the required libraries may be present in the classpath, but the same may not be true in the AWS Lambda environment. Make sure that all the required dependencies are included in the deployment package and that the classpath is set up correctly.

Another solution is to explicitly register the DataContentHandler for the MIME type "multipart/mixed". This can be done by creating a custom implementation of the javax.activation.DataContentHandler interface and registering it with the JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF). Here's an example implementation (untested code):

```
import javax.activation.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyDataContentHandler implements DataContentHandler {
    public MyDataContentHandler() {
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return new DataFlavor[] { new DataFlavor("multipart/mixed") };
    }

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor, DataSource dataSource)
        throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        if (flavor.equals(new DataFlavor("multipart/mixed"))) {
            return dataSource.getInputStream();
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }
    }

    public Object getContent(DataSource dataSource) throws IOException {
        return dataSource.getInputStream();
    }

    public void writeTo(Object object, String mimeType, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedEncodingException("writeTo() not supported");
    }
}
```

Then, register the custom DataContentHandler with the JAF in the Lambda function code before sending the email:

```
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
mc.addMailcap("multipart/mixed;; x-java-content-handler=com.example.MyDataContentHandler"); 
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
```

This should register the custom DataContentHandler for the MIME type "multipart/mixed" and resolve the issue.

Make sure to check the AWS Lambda environment configuration and include all the required dependencies in the deployment package to ensure that the necessary libraries are available at runtime.